# Exporting a variable with multipule values to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm using PowerShell to try and get a specific field from a CSV, store it as a variable, and output it as another csv. This is mainly because I want to use it as part of a larger script, but I'm having problems...

```
Import-Csv C:\EmailsListNoBlanks.csv | ForEach-Object{
$Email = $_.Member -split ';'
}
$Email | Out-File C:\EmailListCOMP.csv
```

However in my CSV I'm only ever getting the last 4 values, whereas I'm expecting a few hundred...

Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks
Matt

Comment: The ForeEach-Object will process each 'line' of the csv file, you are looping and setting $Email each time and then outside the loop are piping $email to the file, after it has processed the last item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something similar to what you are attempting to do and this is what I came up with to have each item on it's own line in the output:

```
Import-Csv C:\EmailsListNoBlanks.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $Email += ($_.Member -split ';') + ("`n")
}
$Email | Out-File C:\EmailListCOMP.csv
```

The output is not in a csv format, but just a regular text file.  The `n adds a newline to the text so that the output is one entry per line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Collections

$Email = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()

Import-Csv C:\EmailsListNoBlanks.csv | ForEach-Object{
    [void]$Email.Add( $_.Member -split ';' )
}
$Email | Out-File C:\EmailListCOMP.csv
```